# What did I do wrong on this Triage review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, triage

I was just doing some Triage review. Apparently, I came across a test which I did not pass, which I cannot understand. My decision was flagging it as off-topic, since it has nothing to do with programming itself. However, I failed the test.
[This is the review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/11497031), please tell me what I did wrong on this one. Could it be that only because the post has many up-votes, it is marked as ok?

Comment: You should link to the audit, not post a picture of it.

Comment: Sorry for that, see the updated post.

Comment: You voted to close a question with *43* helpful votes. That's a record afaik.  Stop, look, listen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is a question about a tool used for programming.  That is *on* topic, as per the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> … if your question generally covers…
>
> - a specific programming problem, or
> - a software algorithm, or
> - **software tools commonly used by programmers**; and is
> - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development
>
> …then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Comment: But it is not about programming. It's about a tool, just as you said.

Comment: @LinusG. And that's on topic.  Questions related to the use of tools used while programming are appropriate.

Comment: @LinusG. The [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on-topic.

Comment: @LinusG. ***Finding*** tools is off-topic, not asking about specific workings, options etc.